# How to exclude some word in regexp in javascript to replace string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select all number from string but exclude h1
and color:#b40000 and color:#0000b4 and color:#00b400.

Example

```
<h1 style="color:#b40000">【Level: LV1 (1/100)】</h1>
<h1 style="color:#0000b4">【Level: LV2 (1/500)】</h1>
<h1 style="color:#00b400">【Level: LV3 (1/1000)】</h1>
【Attributes: Strength 2, Toughness 2, Wisdom 2, Spirit 2, Agility 2, Charisma 2, Luck 2. Evaluation: 2 】
```

I tried this

```
/(\d[^>|(color:#b40000)|(color:#0000b4)|(color:#00b400)|h(?!1)]|[^>|(color:#b40000)|(color:#0000b4)|(color:#00b400)|h(?!1)])(\d+)/g
```

but i get V1 instead of 1 and 1/100 instead 1 and 100 (i don't want '/' in 1/100)

This is my test script https://regexr.com/6i8k0
[image]

Please tell me how to make it become like this
[image]

EDIT: I mean, please correct my script in https://regexr.com/6i8k0 to become like in screenshot 2.
EDIT 2: I mean not HTML but string like this

```
h1 b40000【Level: LV1 (1/100)】h1
h1 0000b4【Level: LV2 (1/500)】h1
h1 00b400【Level: LV3 (1/1000)】h1
【Attributes: Strength 2, Toughness 2, Wisdom 2, Spirit 2, Agility 2, Charisma 2, Luck 2. Evaluation: 2】
```

i want to selete all digit  from this example string to replace with something but i want to exclude digit 1 from h1, b40000, 0000b4, 00b400(if i use \d it'll include digit 1 from h1 and other)
i don't know how to filter this, please teach me
I'm new in regex so if you use https://regexr.com/ to teach it'll be earier for me to understand
sorry for my bad in english
thanks you

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex must be avoided

Comment: what do you want in output? 1 100 ??

Comment: Where your code will be executed? How are getting this data? Does it come from the browser page or are you getting it as a string?

Comment: As I understood you need 1 100, 1 500, 1 1000 from the above HTML. Use `re.findall(r"(?:[^(]*)(\d+)/(\d+)(?:[^)]*)", HTML)` it will return `[('1', '100'), ('1', '500'), ('1', '1000')]`. If it was not answer you expected then please clearify your question and add the expected result (it would be better to see the expected result as a Python's data structure).

Comment: can you go to https://regexr.com/6i8k0 and correct my script to become like in screen shot 2